# Searching lower value into array returns "Out of GAS" before complete the total loop

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I developed a smart contract that store data in a struct array.
Frequenlty the other function is calling the function `getLowerLastDate()` to known the lower `LastDate` and the related `Wallet` of all accounts.

The problem is when the `Acounts` array has about 500 records (just. I am afraid because could have millions), the transaction is reverted by block `out of GAS`

I am not sure how to solve this blockchain handicap because I need to know the lower `LastDate` for the correct smart contract operation.

Any ideas or hints are appreciated.

```
struct StructAccount { 
  uint256 Index; 
  address Wallet; 
  uint256 Balance; 
  uint256 Time; 
  uint256 RegDate;
  uint256 LastDate;
  }  

StructAccount[] public Accounts;


function getLowerLastDate() public view returns (uint, address) {
  uint    lowerDate = block.timestamp;
  uint    Key = 0;
  for (uint i = 0; i < Accounts.length; i++) {
    if(Accounts[i].LastDate != 0){
        if( Accounts[i].LastDate <= lowerDate ){
            lowerDate = Accounts[i].LastDate;
            Key = i;
        }
    }
  }
  Accounts[Key].LastDate = 0; //reset and search the next lower LastDate
  return (lowerDate, Accounts[Key].Wallet) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you create each `StructAccount`, but you can create a new global variable called `lowestLastDate`, and everytime you create a `StructAccount`, compare it against the value of `lowestLastDate`, and if it is lower, then make it the new value of `lowestLastDate`.

Whenever you want to access the value of the lower LastDate, you get it right from the variable. This allows you to access the lowest late date in O(1) time but will cost more gas to initialize each `StructAccount`

Comment: Maybe i can store in a int[] array the indexes of Accounts[] structure and search on it. I am not sure how many elements could have  it. And I am not sure if I could concat or sort arrays with low gas costs when the info needs to reordered

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you out with that.

The first approach you could try, and the simplest one, is to make a local/memory copy of the `Accounts` array. Because reading and from storage in a loop consumes a lot of gas.

Check the gas cost of common opcodes like `SLOAD`, `SSTORE`, `MLOAD`, `MSTORE`.

So, I would refactor your code like this:

```js
contract Contract {
    struct StructAccount { 
        uint256 Index; 
        address Wallet; 
        uint256 Balance; 
        uint256 Time; 
        uint256 RegDate;
        uint256 LastDate;
    }  

    StructAccount[] public Accounts;

    function getLowerLastDate() public returns (uint, address) {
        StructAccount[] memory accountsCopy = Accounts;
        uint lowerDate = block.timestamp;
        uint Key = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < accountsCopy.length; i++) {
            if(accountsCopy[i].LastDate != 0){
                if( accountsCopy[i].LastDate <= lowerDate ){
                    lowerDate = accountsCopy[i].LastDate;
                    Key = i;
                }
            }
        }

        // We can leave this line as is, since we need to update the state Accounts array at least once here.
        Accounts[Key].LastDate = 0; //reset and search the next lower LastDate
        return (lowerDate, accountsCopy[Key].Wallet);
    }
}
```

Notice how I made a copy in memory of the array. This way it will be cheaper to read from memory than from storage.

Also, it's perfectly valid to do something like the following. Copying a state array, operating on it, and then assigning it back to the state array, once.

```js
contract Contract {

    uint256[] public numbers;

    uint256 public counter;

    function addNumber() public {
        numbers.push(counter++);
    }

    function doOperation() public {

        uint256[] memory counterCopy = numbers;

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < counterCopy.length; i++) {
            counterCopy[i] = counterCopy[i] * 2;
        }

        numbers = counterCopy; // This is valid.

    }

}
```

Now, this will probably not solve all your future issues when you have so many records (millions?). As you see, iterating through an array that has so many records is not ideal, not even in memory. It would be really expensive and you would probably get an out-of-gas exception anyways.

That brings us to a second approach:

Recording a `StructAccount` instance with the lowest `LastDate` everytime it is added/updated.

Take at the function `addStructAccount` (I don't know if this is the way you are adding the accounts, but it's just an example of what you could do).
Notice how I'm always checking if the new account has a lower LastDate, and if so, I replace the `structWithLowestLastDate` state variable with it.
We can do this also when updating any account.

```js
contract Contract {

    struct StructAccount { 
        uint256 Index; 
        address Wallet; 
        uint256 Balance; 
        uint256 Time; 
        uint256 RegDate;
        uint256 LastDate;
    }

    StructAccount public structWithLowestLastDate;

    StructAccount[] public Accounts;

    function addStructAccount(uint256 index, address wallet, uint256 balance, uint256 time, uint256 regDate, uint256 lastDate) public {

        StructAccount memory account = StructAccount(index, wallet, balance, time, regDate, lastDate);

        // Keeping the account with the lowest LastData in a storage variable of its own, this way we don't need to look for it in the array
        if(lastDate < structWithLowestLastDate.LastDate) {
            structWithLowestLastDate = account;
        }

        // Adding the account to the storage array as usual. 
        Accounts.push(account);

    }

    function getLowerLastDate() public returns (uint, address) {
        StructAccount[] memory accountsCopy = Accounts;
        uint lowerDate = block.timestamp;
        uint Key = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < accountsCopy.length; i++) {
            if(accountsCopy[i].LastDate != 0){
                if( accountsCopy[i].LastDate <= lowerDate ){
                    lowerDate = accountsCopy[i].LastDate;
                    Key = i;
                }
            }
        }

        // We can leave this line as is, since we need to update the state Accounts array at least once here.
        Accounts[Key].LastDate = 0; //reset and search the next lower LastDate
        return (lowerDate, accountsCopy[Key].Wallet);
    }
}
```

Maybe this approach will not work for you either, since I see that when you `getLowerLastDate()`, you reset it and if you call it again you are expecting the find the next account with the lowest LastDate.

For this, maybe you would want to implement a `minHeap` so you always have the lower LastDate account as the first element and you can `peek()` it in constant time, or `pop()` it in `O(log n)` time.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/min-heap-binary-tree

If you are going to have so many records in the smart contract, maybe you could think about moving that data to a regular backend/database, if it does not require decentralization, etc. Or to an IPFS.

Or maybe you could have logic to remove the data from the array that you no longer need. This way, you keep the array at a reasonable size.

I'll try to implement a `minHeap` in Solidity and see how it works...

Well, I found a max heap implementation here: https://github.com/Dev43/heap-solidity

You could easily transform it into a min-heap.

Comment: An alternative option is store in a int[] array the indexes of Accounts[] structure and search on it. I am not sure how many elements could have  it. And I am not sure if I could sort or concat arrays with low gas costs